# The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables. after it's casting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

I have one stored procedure for getting job info. I cast ntext to nvarchar(max) but still getting error like :

```
Msg 2739, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.
Msg 2739, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.
Msg 2739, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.
```

here is my stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetJobInfo]
    (
    @jobId int,
    @subject text OUTPUT,
    @plainText1 nvarchar(max) OUTPUT,
    @ToUser text OUTPUT,
    @Cc text OUTPUT,
    @templateID int OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT TOP 1 @subject = p.[Title],
        @plainText1 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),p.[Body]),
        @ToUser =p.[ToUser],
        @Cc =p.[Cc],
        @templateID =p.[template_id]
        FROM [tbl_Email_master] p INNER JOIN
        [Jobs] j ON p.[Id] =
        j.[PreparedEmailID]
        WHERE j.[JobID] = @jobId
    RETURN
END
```

What's going wrong here.please help me...

Comment: But `@subject`, `@ToUser` and `@Cc` are still `text` datatypes. Why are you even using `text`, it's been deprecated for 14 years.

Comment: sorry I forgot. thanks for your answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have parameters of type `TEXT` (`@ToUser`,  `@Cc`...), change them to `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` accordingly to the values they are gonna hold, in the SP parameters definition. For emails, it's probably gonna be `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

`TEXT`, `NTEXT` and `IMAGE` are gonna [be deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017), refrain from using it from now on and try to update it whenever you see it on code.

Comment: They're not going to be deprecated, they already are, and have been for 14 years. :)